# getting started with google directory API and device management

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api, google-reseller-api

Heyy, I was looking into Google apps for business and playing with the API explorer ... I have a reseller account with google let's say stack@reseller.goteam.com and this works for creating users, org units, subscriptions and so. 
I want to start with the device management and investigating on these things:

1) How do I know my customerId from google cpanel ... I am looking to know how to see the info required for these requests in CPanel.

2) I am getting the below error:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

In my request, I entered "goteam.com" as customerId..... Isn't this correct? any good posts on getting started with device management.... Please help

Answer (score 1):

1. there are 2 basic ways to determine what customerId you need to use:

   - Just use `my_customer`, this will use the customerId of the user you authenticated as. This works perfect when working with your own domain but will not work when when you are a reseller trying to access one of your customer's domain data.
   - Use the users.list() API call to determine the customerId. Specify the domain, a maxResult of 1 and that the only field you want back is customerId. [Here's what it'd look like in the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/admin/directory_v1/directory.users.list?domain=goteam.com&maxResults=1&fields=users%252FcustomerId&_h=1&).
2. The customerId is not your domain, it's a unique ID that looks like random characters.

Lastly, you should be aware that [resellers currently can't make device management requests for customers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices) (see note near top).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jay. Currently resellers cannot utilize the Directory API on behalf of their customers.  The Provisioning API does however, work.

Comment: Update: Resellers can utilize the Directory API on behalf of newly provisioned customers -- or for folks that have "Enable Reseller to Access my Console" checked.